# Этимология слова "супостат"

Tags: этимология

Супостат - это враг, антагонист. А вот интересно было бы узнать происхождения этого слова. По идее, оно русское (не заимствование), но от какого корня может происходить, честно говоря, не могу даже предположить. Или оно все-таки иностранное?
Мне сейчас подумалось, что оно каким-то образом родственно слову "супротив", то есть, "против".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Буквальный смысл - противопоставленный, противостоящий, то есть противник. Родственно старо-славянской форме слова "со(у)поставить" в значении "поставить друг против друга"(съпостати) - через образование страдательного причастия.

Comment: Скорее сопоставить для сравнения, чем противопоставить.

Answer (score -1):

СУ-ПО-СТ-ат - слово происходит от приставки СУ + приставки ПО + корня СТа + суффикс Т.
корень СТ обозначает число 100, от него образованы слова СТо, СТа, СоТа, СТою, СТоят, СТоим, 
приставка ПО в данном случае обозначает число 14, значение которого известно из древнего иврита. и обозначает в т.ч. ПРОТИВ, от него также образованы приставки аН, аНти, обозначающие все то же против и число 14.
приставка Су тождественна приставке СО, обозначает число 21 и понятие ДУ-Ализма и понятие вместе.
Итого Су+По+Ста-Т = СО-ПРОТИВ-СТа = ПРОТИВо СТОящий

Comment: Действия не требуется. Если расковырять, так потом незаковырять.